# passing interface as a argument in between usecases and repositories

Tags: dart, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I want to pass `interface` as a request in my use cases and repositories while following the clean architecture in `flutter`

hence my method signature is as follows for `usecases` and `respositories` respectively.

```
Future<Either<Failure, ResponseData>> call(IRequest params) // use case
Future<Either<Failure, ResponseData>> updateUserProfile(IRequest request); // repository
```

Now request `entities` and `models` are as follows

```
//Entity
class UserProfileRequestData  implements IRequest{


  late final int id;
  late final String first_name;
  late final String last_name;
  
   UserProfileRequestData(
      {required this.id,
      required this.first_name,
      required this.last_name});
      
 @override
  Object toRequest() {
    // TODO: implement toRequest
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}

//Model
class UserProfileRequestDataModel extends UserProfileRequestData implements IRequest {

     UserProfileRequestDataModel({
        required int id,
        required String first_name,
        required String last_name,}):super( id: id,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,);
            
     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "first_name": first_name,
      "last_name": last_name,
      "id": id,
      };
   }
    @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toRequest() => toJson();


}
```

Now, what I am expecting is whenever the user passes `UserProfileRequestData` as an entity from UI and in repository if I execture `request.toRequest()` then it should call `UserProfileRequestDataModel`'s  `toRequest()` function and not the parent class one.

here is the sample code [for this problem statement](https://gist.github.com/ntimesc/9bb5ef756dba1f0613c122818b7a49e4)